# setting DNS on a Fresh Ubuntu VPS

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, vps

okay here my problem,
im still new with something called "DNS",
after all these years i'm only using cPanel & DirectAdmin for setting the dns

and now, i've bought a new vps, comes with Ubuntu 10.04 and nothing else...
i manually install nginx + php + mysql, and done, everything goes normal

so one thing that i want to ask, the last one step... setting the dns...
i've changed the ip adrress and everything needed on the domain registrar, and it has been 1 day, even google dns server fails to resolve it...

anyone knows?
step that i miss on the VPS side...

Answer (score 1):

You aren't exactly clear with what your problem is.

First, you need to set up DNS servers to include:
A records (i.e., www.mysite.com -> 1.1.1.1)
MX records (i.e., "route mail for mysite.com" to the following list of servers)
CNAME records if required (i.e., resolve mysite.com -> www.mysite.com)

THEN, you have to tell the domain registrar to use the DNS servers you've set up.

What you probably want to consider doing is using your host's DNS servers which will give you a nice, friendly (hopefully!) web interface to setting up the DNS.